# How to fill a shape in easeljs with an image commpletely without repetetion?

Tags: createjs, easeljs

I want to fill this round rectangle with an image. I am using bitmap fill.

```
            var stage = new createjs.Stage("canvas");
            var layoutWidth = 0.8 * stage.canvas.width;
            var layoutHeight = 0.6 * stage.canvas.height;
            var layoutRect = new createjs.Shape();
            var image = new createjs.Bitmap("insta.png");
            image.image.onload=function(){
                    layoutRect.graphics.beginStroke("black").beginBitmapFill(image.image).drawRoundRect((stage.canvas.width - layoutWidth) / 2, (stage.canvas.height - layoutHeight) / 2, layoutWidth, layoutHeight,20);
                    stage.update();
            }
            stage.addChild(layoutRect);
            stage.update();
```

How to fill this shape completely with one image and no repetetion. I want that one image should occupy the entire space of the shape.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a matrix transform on the fill to affect the scale and translation of the image fill.

```
var m = new createjs.Matrix2D();
m.translate(x, y);
m.scale(targetWidth/imageWidth, targetHeight/imageHeight);
graphics.beginBitmapFill(img, "no-repeat", m);
```

Here is a sample fiddle based on your code: http://jsfiddle.net/x0oqrkwv/

If you want to maintain aspect ratio, you will have to add logic to do that.